# Binary tree folding

Tags: scala, tree, fold

I have been given the following definition of a binary tree

```
abstract class Tree[+A]
case class Leaf[A](value: A) extends Tree[A]
case class Node[A](value: A, left: Tree[A], right: Tree[A]) extends Tree[A]
```

and the following function

```
def fold_tree[A,B](f1: A => B)(f2: (A, B, B) => B)(t: Tree[A]): B = t match {
    case Leaf(value) => f1(value)
    case Node(value, l, r) => f2(value, fold_tree(f1)(f2)(l), fold_tree(f1)(f2)(r)) //post order
  }
```

I have been asked to return the rightmost value in the tree using the fold method. How would this work? I'm not sure I fully understand fold, but I thought the point of fold was to do some operation to every element in the tree. How can I use it to just return the rightmost value of a tree?

I am also unsure as to how to call the method. I keep getting issues with unspecified parameter type. Can someone show me the proper way to call this fold_tree method?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Sure. Im pretty lost. I first wanted to try just to call the function and see what the result would be. I'm pretty new to scala and I'm not really sure how to input the correct variables/types. I've messed around with things like
    fold_tree[A,Int]( t => 1)(t,t,t => 1)(t)
just to see if I could get the method to run at all and return one somehow but I don't think I'm understanding it correctly.

Comment: Actually, I may have figured out how to do it. Could you confirm/deny this reasoning?     fold_tree[A,A]( t => t)((t,x,z) => z)(t)
this should work because the method takes in type A and returns type A. It tells the method if we are at a leaf, just return the leafs value. If we have a node and a left tree and a right tree, return the right tree's value. Is that correct?

Comment: Yep! Post it as an answer and accept it! Couple style comments: `t => t` is defined as `identity`, and it is usually good practice to put underscores in the place of arguments you won't use: `(_,_,z) => z`.

Comment: Are you planning to post all the issues you have with your assignment on SO?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How would this work? I'm not sure I fully understand fold

What your `foldTree` method is doing is recursively walking the tree, applying itself to each `Node` or `Leaf` it encounters in the way. The method also has two type parameters that need to be applied, `A` and `B`, depending on the type of the provided tree.

Let's for the sake of the example say we have a `Tree[Int]` defined like this:

```
val n = Node(1, Leaf(2), Node(3, Leaf(5), Node(4, Leaf(42), Leaf(50))))
```

The tree has a structure that looks like this:

[image: Tree]

We want to get the right most value, which is 50. In order to do that with the current implementation of `foldTree`, we need to provide it two methods:

1. `f1: A => B`: Given an `A`, project a `B` value
2. `f2: (A, B, B) => B`: Given one `A` and two `B` values, project a `B`.

We can see that `f1` is applied over a `Leaf`, and `f2` is applied over a `Node` (hence the different number of elements provided to each method). So this gives us a hint that the functions we provide to `foldTree` will be applied to each one, respectively.

Packed with that knowledge, given our tree:

```
val n = Node(1, Leaf(2), Node(3, Leaf(55), Node(4, Leaf(42), Leaf(50))))
```

We provide the following method:

```
println(foldTree[Int, Int](identity)((x, y, z) => z)(n))
```

What this means is as follows:

1. If we encounter a `Leaf` node and map over it (by applying `f1` on it), we simply want to extract it's value.
2. When encountering a `Node` element (and applying `f2` to it), we want to take the *right most element*, which is projected by the third element `z` in our method.

Running this, yields the expected result: `50`.

If we want to expand this generically for any `A`, we can say:

```
def extractRightmostValue[A](tree: Tree[A]) =
  foldTree[A, A](identity)((x, y, z) => z)(tree)
```

Comment: Thank you! Just to confirm, the reason we say [Int, Int] here is because this binary tree only contains integers, is that correct? I am using [A,A] in my code and that is working. Is that because the tree/nodes/leafs and the function are all using A?

Comment: @Vandexel Yes, that's correct. If I create a `Tree[A]`, that means I can apply any `A`. In this case, I chose to apply it on a `Tree[Int]`. But, if you want to apply it generically to any `A`, then you can do it as you did.

Comment: I've been having some trouble understanding another one. This one asks me to return a mirror of a tree where left and right subtrees are recursively flipped. So  Node(4,Leaf(1),Leaf(2)) would produce Node(4,Leaf(2),Leaf(1)) for example. I'm not sure why this doesn't work:
    fold_tree[A,A](t => t)((x,y,z) => (x,z,y)(t)
To me this says: Takes Type A and returns Type A. We pass in a tree, it says if it is a leaf, return itself, it is a node, return itself with lt and rt flipped. But this gives me type mismatch: Required A, found (A,A,A). What does this mean?How am I thinking about this wrong?

Comment: I will ask this in another question to make it more clear

Answer (score 0):

```
fold_tree[A,A](identity)((_,_,z) => z)(t)
```

This should work because the method takes in type A and returns type A. It tells the method if we are at a leaf, just return the leafs value. If we have a node and a left tree and a right tree, return the right tree's value.